# Generate number other than primary key

Tags: key

I have a table called "Member". It has a primary key "PersonID" who is foreign. The table "Member" also has a field called "MemberNumber". I want "MemberNumber" to automaticaly increment. The Identity option is used for "PersonID". How do I generate a number for "MemberNumber"?

Example how I want it to be:

Table Person:

```
--------------------------------------------------
       PersonID (PK)   |       Name              |
--------------------------------------------------
       1               |          Bob            |
--------------------------------------------------
       2               |          Sam            |
--------------------------------------------------
       3               |          Tom            |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Table Member:

```
--------------------------------------------------
    PersonID (PK & FK) |   MemberNumber          |
--------------------------------------------------
       1               |          1              |
--------------------------------------------------
       3               |          2              | 
--------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: @AlmaDo SqlServer 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you really mean and how do you want this solved.
My Problem is that i don't know the context you are talking about. Maybe by being a bit more specific could help. But i will try to do my best and give some (possible?) answers.

1. You can create a variable for your MemberNumber which you increment with each new entry. If you don't delete entries it's also possible to get the length of the table, add one and insert this as a new entry.
2. You can look at the last entry to get the highest MemberNumber, add one and insert this as a new entry. (Very similiar to the solution without deleting, but you can delete with this)

Comment: @Dancelgel Person has attributes like name, first name, address, etc. Member inherits the fields from Person (including PersonID) and has some fields of his own like memberfunction, member since, etc. My problem is when I create a member i want the database to automaticaly increment the MemberNumber.

Comment: @Dancelgel I will try your second option that sounds very good.